# iBooks JavaScript resources

Tags: javascript, ios, epub, ibooks

iBooks [recently](http://blog.threepress.org/2010/06/24/javascript-and-interactivity-in-ibooks/) [started](http://www.pigsgourdsandwikis.com/2011/06/javascript-accepted-in-ibookstore.html) [supporting](http://www.walrus-books.com/2011/06/epubdemo3/) JavaScript inside epub. Where is this documented?

Are there any code examples to get started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

** Update, one year later : This has been now documented for several months in the official Apple Docs available on iTunes Connect

---

From what i've seen, you already have quoted the best known sources.

I think that it is not documented anywhere in the official docs from Apple. Here are some elements from what I've experienced.

**Features supported by iBooks**

A lot of things that work on Safari work on iBooks too. You already have access to HTML5 features like internal DB, canvas, etc. The biggest problems I saw were related to slowness and vertical positionning. There are problems with pagination too : if you add content, pages are not added to the end and the content can overflow.

**Validation for the iBookStore**

Before being published on the iBookStore, it relates entirely on Apple's arbitrary validation when it comes to Javascript. I know at least one [ePub with interactive forms and DB](http://itunes.apple.com/fr/book/boostez-votre-score-au-toeic/id419876391?ls=1), that they have validated.

Comment: _Update, one year later : This has been now documented for several months in the official Apple Docs available on iTunes Connect_: Could you post a link to that? It's hard to find sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

For lack of better resources, I created a open-source [example](https://github.com/robotmedia/iBooks-ePub-Samples) of using JQuery to show an alert. Might be helpful as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

The examples you give refer to the interactivity in the body of the books. Javascript scripting can also be used within the HTML widgets:

HTML widget boiler plate on github -- https://github.com/TrevorBurnham/iBooks-HTML-Widget-Boilerplate.

iBook Widgets with D3.js -- 
http://vallandingham.me/ibooks_and_d3.html
(to check the widget, click on 'download a copy of my iBook file', change the iba extension to 'zip', uncompress, navigate to vis-1.wdgt)